# Threshold Signature with Accumulation Scheme?

Tags: signature, threshold-cryptography

Is there a threshold signature scheme that can be accumulated? That is, given a message $M$ signed by $k-1$ parties and the $(k-1)$-threshold signature $\sigma_{k-1}$, a party can verify $\sigma_{k-1}$ is indeed signed by $k-1$ distinct parties, and can add its partial signature to it to obtain a $k$-threshold signature $\sigma_k$.

I am aware that the standard multi-signature scheme can achieve this, but it needs to attach a list of signers with the signature, which costs $O(n)$. Is there a signature scheme that achieves this and only has sublinear communication cost? Any related reference would be appreciated!